# Trying to remove theme

Tags: magento2, theme, exception, dependency

We've had endless headaches with a theme we purchased when we first launched our site so we are trying to finally migrate away from it, but it's not letting go easily.

Whenever I am trying to begin with the products, switching them off the default theme. But when I switch it off the Cleversoft Novetty and try to use something like Magento Blank or Magento Luma, Cleversoft is still throwing errors.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how I can quick-fix something like this?

The current error I'm getting seems to be something injected in the page header, but I'm not entirely certain why it's throwing an error as I would assume it could still find what it needs in the theme files. (some dependency in sub/page theme content through bad compartmentalizing of code?)

The error I get when I switch a product to blank is:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Magento_Customer::account/link/authorization_mobile.phtml' in module: 'CleverSoft_Base' block's name: 'authorization-link-mobile'

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Magento_Customer::account/link/authorization_mobile.phtml' in module: 'CleverSoft_Base' block's name: 'authorization-link-mobile'
#0 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView(false)
#1 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Link.php(101): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#2 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link->_toHtml()
#3 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#4 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('authorization-l...')
#5 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('authorization-l...')
#6 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('renderNonCached...', Array)
#7 /srv/magento/vendor/mage2pro/core/Framework/Plugin/View/Layout.php(166): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('authorization-l...')
#8 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Df\Framework\Plugin\View\Layout->aroundRenderNonCachedElement(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor), Object(Closure), 'authorization-l...')
#9 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('authorization-l...')
#10 /srv/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderNonCached...', Array, NULL)
#11 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('authorization-l...')
#12 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Links.php(62): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('authorization-l...')
#13 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Links.php(82): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links->renderLink(Object(CleverSoft\Base\Block\AuthorizationLink\Interceptor))
#14 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links->_toHtml()
#15 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#16 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('header.links.mo...')
#17 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('header.links.mo...')
#18 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('renderNonCached...', Array)
#19 /srv/magento/vendor/mage2pro/core/Framework/Plugin/View/Layout.php(166): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('header.links.mo...')
#20 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Df\Framework\Plugin\View\Layout->aroundRenderNonCachedElement(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor), Object(Closure), 'header.links.mo...')
#21 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('header.links.mo...')
#22 /srv/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderNonCached...', Array, NULL)
#23 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('header.links.mo...')
#24 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(511): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('header.links.mo...', true)
#25 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/container.phtml(10): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml()
#26 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/srv/magento/ve...')
#27 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Interceptor), '/srv/magento/ve...', Array)
#28 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callParent('render', Array)
#29 /srv/magento/vendor/mage2pro/core/Framework/Plugin/View/TemplateEngineInterface.php(21): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Interceptor), '/srv/magento/ve...', Array)
#30 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Df\Framework\Plugin\View\TemplateEngineInterface->aroundRender(Object(Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Interceptor), '/srv/magento/ve...', Array)
#31 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Interceptor), '/srv/magento/ve...', Array)
#32 /srv/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callPlugins('render', Array, NULL)
#33 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->render(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Interceptor), '/srv/magento/ve...', Array)
#34 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/srv/magento/ve...')
#35 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#36 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#37 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('store.menu')
#38 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('store.menu')
#39 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('renderNonCached...', Array)
#40 /srv/magento/vendor/mage2pro/core/Framework/Plugin/View/Layout.php(166): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('store.menu')
#41 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Df\Framework\Plugin\View\Layout->aroundRenderNonCachedElement(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor), Object(Closure), 'store.menu')
#42 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('store.menu')
#43 /srv/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderNonCached...', Array, NULL)
#44 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('store.menu')
#45 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/sections.phtml(26): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('store.menu')
#46 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/srv/magento/ve...')
#47 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Interceptor), '/srv/magento/ve...', Array)
#48 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callParent('render', Array)
#49 /srv/magento/vendor/mage2pro/core/Framework/Plugin/View/TemplateEngineInterface.php(21): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Interceptor), '/srv/magento/ve...', Array)
#50 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Df\Framework\Plugin\View\TemplateEngineInterface->aroundRender(Object(Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Interceptor), '/srv/magento/ve...', Array)
#51 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Interceptor), '/srv/magento/ve...', Array)
#52 /srv/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callPlugins('render', Array, NULL)
#53 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->render(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Interceptor), '/srv/magento/ve...', Array)
#54 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/srv/magento/ve...')
#55 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#56 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#57 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('navigation.sect...')
#58 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('navigation.sect...')
#59 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('renderNonCached...', Array)
#60 /srv/magento/vendor/mage2pro/core/Framework/Plugin/View/Layout.php(166): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('navigation.sect...')
#61 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Df\Framework\Plugin\View\Layout->aroundRenderNonCachedElement(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor), Object(Closure), 'navigation.sect...')
#62 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('navigation.sect...')
#63 /srv/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderNonCached...', Array, NULL)
#64 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('navigation.sect...')
#65 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('navigation.sect...')
#66 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.top')
#67 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.top')
#68 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('renderNonCached...', Array)
#69 /srv/magento/vendor/mage2pro/core/Framework/Plugin/View/Layout.php(166): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('page.top')
#70 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Df\Framework\Plugin\View\Layout->aroundRenderNonCachedElement(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor), Object(Closure), 'page.top')
#71 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('page.top')
#72 /srv/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderNonCached...', Array, NULL)
#73 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.top')
#74 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.top')
#75 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#76 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#77 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('renderNonCached...', Array)
#78 /srv/magento/vendor/mage2pro/core/Framework/Plugin/View/Layout.php(166): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('page.wrapper')
#79 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Df\Framework\Plugin\View\Layout->aroundRenderNonCachedElement(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor), Object(Closure), 'page.wrapper')
#80 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('page.wrapper')
#81 /srv/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderNonCached...', Array, NULL)
#82 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#83 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#84 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#85 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#86 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('renderNonCached...', Array)
#87 /srv/magento/vendor/mage2pro/core/Framework/Plugin/View/Layout.php(166): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('root')
#88 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Df\Framework\Plugin\View\Layout->aroundRenderNonCachedElement(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor), Object(Closure), 'root')
#89 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('root')
#90 /srv/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderNonCached...', Array, NULL)
#91 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#92 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(954): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root')
#93 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#94 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', Array)
#95 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#96 /srv/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(52): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#97 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(257): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#98 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#99 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#100 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#101 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#102 /srv/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#103 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#104 /srv/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#105 /srv/magento/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#106 {main}
```

Can I just create an override theme template in my custom code that is empty with the same filename? Or is there a better way to address crap-code like this?

Presumably, when we are finished changing over and completely styling a custom theme, it will no longer be an issue as we can convert the whole site's default to the new theme. But that's going to be a lengthy process and I would prefer to do it gradually, migrating content off one piece at a time then thoroughly testing the site again after removing the old theme dependencies to make sure everything still works when finished.

Comment: I think you're getting this error on product detail page, it would be helpful if you can post theme's catalog_product_view.xml or the xml related to the page where you're getting the error.

Comment: If cleversoft has a custom module for its admin configuration try to start on disabling it before doing a theme switch.